# Delete similar object in multiple page pdf - Adobe Acrobat DC pro

Tags: adobe-acrobat

I have a 588 page pdf file.
It has on every page the same objects that need to be deleted.
Does anyone know how to select those same objects on every page and delete them without selecting them one by one? (acrobat DC Pro)

Cheers!